# How to call a parsed number in Phone gap?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Here is HTML file

```
 <div class="email">
<p style ="top:0;"><b id="email"></b</p>
<a href="https://accounts.google.com" style="top:10px;">
<img class="imgleft" src="css/gmail.png" style="height:30px;"/></a>

<p style ="top:30px; color:#45b3e0;"><b id="phone"></b></p>
<a href="#" onclick ='return phoneNumber()'style="top:45px;">
<img class="imgleft" src="css/phone.png" style="height:20px;"/></a>
</div>
```

Here is JS file

```
function getInformation(){

var address,companyEmail,companyName,companyPhone,followupDate,leadDate,leadDetails,leadValue,contactPerson,followupAction,status;

address=localStorage.getItem("Address");
companyEmail=localStorage.getItem("companyemail");
companyName=localStorage.getItem("companyname");
companyPhone=localStorage.getItem("companyphone");
followupDate=localStorage.getItem("followupdate");
leadDate=localStorage.getItem("leaddate");
leadDetails=localStorage.getItem("leaddetails");
leadValue=localStorage.getItem("leadvalue");
contactPerson=localStorage.getItem("contactperson");
followupAction=localStorage.getItem("followupaction");
status=localStorage.getItem("Status");

//document.getElementById("description").innerHTML=Address;
document.getElementById("email").innerHTML=companyEmail;
document.getElementById("cname").innerHTML=companyName;
document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML=companyPhone;
document.getElementById("fdate").innerHTML=followupDate;
document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML=address;
document.getElementById("ldetail").innerHTML=leadDetails;
document.getElementById("lvalue").innerHTML=leadValue;
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=contactPerson;
document.getElementById("faction").innerHTML=followupAction;
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=status;   }
function phoneNumber(phone)
 {

    phone = Phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    window.location = "tel:" + phone;
  }
```

I am  working on Phone Gap application for android and IOS, Here I'm getting able to Parse Phone Number and Mail ID from the server but my question
1. when user click on call image that parsed number should get dial and same thing for Mailing?

Answer (score 1):

Change html code as following

```
<div class="email">
    <p style ="top:0;"><b id="email"></b</p>
    <a href="mailto:test@gmail.com" style="top:10px;">
    <img class="imgleft" src="css/gmail.png" style="height:30px;"/></a>

    <p style ="top:30px; color:#45b3e0;"><b id="phone"></b></p>
    <a href="tel:+910000000000"> +91 00000 00000 style="top:45px;">
    <img class="imgleft" src="css/phone.png" style="height:20px;"/></a>
    </div>
```

And add following in your config.xml file

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="mailto:*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
```

it will open native mail system and native dialer to make phone calls.

Answer (score 0):

add in config.xml

```
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
```

[check this link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)

and in html

```
<a href="mailto:test@email.com">text</a>
<a href="tel:1234">text</a>
```

Comment: I dont want to call static number ,parsed number should get dial .when i click on phone.png image

Comment: window.open('tel:'+PhoneNumber);
or
window.location.href="tel://"+PhoneNumber;  try this

Comment: replace PhoneNumber with your value     function phoneNumber(phone)
 {

    phone = Phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    window.open('tel:'+phone);  or window.location.href="tel://"+phone ;
  }